# Data syncing with pouchdb-based systems client-side: is there a workaround to the 'deleted' flag?

Tags: postgresql, hasura, rxdb, pouchdb-adapter-localstorage

I'm planning on using rxdb + hasura/postgresql in the backend. I'm reading [this rxdb page](https://rxdb.info/replication-graphql.html) for example, which off the bat requires sync-able entities to have a `deleted` flag.

### Q1 (main question)

- Is there **ANY** point at which I can finally **hard-delete** these entities? What conditions would have to be met - eg could I simply use "older than X months" and then force my app to only ever displays data for less than X months?
- Is such a hard-delete, if possible, best carried out directly in the central db, since it will be the source of truth? Would there be any repercussions client-side that I'm not foreseeing/understanding?

I foresee the number of `deleted`'s growing rapidly in my app and i don't want to have to store all this extra data forever.

**Q2 (bonus / just curious)**

- What is the (algorithmic) basis for needing a 'deleted' flag? Is it that it's just faster to check a flag rather than to check for the omission of an object from, say, a very large list. I apologize if it's kind of a stupid question :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately it comes down to a decision that's informed by your particular business/product with regards to how long you want to keep deleted entities in your system. For some applications it's important to always keep a history of deleted things or even individual revisions to records stored as a kind of ledger or history. You'll have to make a judgement call as to how long you want to keep your deleted entities.

I'd recommend that you also add a `deleted_at` column if you haven't already and then you could easily leverage something like Hasura's new [Scheduled Triggers functionality](https://hasura.io/docs/1.0/graphql/core/scheduled-triggers/index.html) to run a recurring job that fully deletes records older than whatever your threshold is.

You could also leverage Hasura's permissions system to ensure that rows that have been deleted aren't returned to the client. There is [documentation and examples](https://hasura.io/docs/1.0/graphql/core/guides/data-modelling/soft-deletes.html) for ways to work with soft deletes and Hasura

For your second question it is definitely much faster to check for the deleted flag on records than to have to try and diff the entire dataset looking for things that are now missing.